# Trying to update data from SOAP cal thru web-service but only few fields are updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

In my web project I am fetching customer details from SQL DB server thru web-service and soap-call, and showing the same in web page (personal-details). Users can update their personal details from page. My problem is that- some users are new and we have only their DOB and CustomerId in database. Now I am trying to update new users details from page, all things are working fine but address and city is not updating. Here is website link with userid and password. https://www.starbazaarindia.com/test/index.aspx UserId (clubcard no)- SBS0050600092310 and password (DOB)- 19051985.

https://www.starbazaarindia.com/test/index.aspx

Comment: Can you post the code from the page that is trying to save this info?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a debug break point on the service being called and [debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291236%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The service post is https and returns a 200 so without changing that or debugging we are blind to the error.

I suspect 5 mins in the debugger you will have a head-slap moment, then fix it.